# How are types determined?

Tags: haskell

I've written some xyz program, and prints something on the screen, very irrelevant. In this code I'm finding that if I remove a line which is not related to what I want to print I'm getting an error.

```
import Data.Array

horizontal inArray limit listLen = [ findProd i j | i<-[1..limit], j<-[1..(limit - listLen)]]
            where 
            findProd a b = product [ inArray!(a,b+k) | k<-[0..(listLen-1)] ]

vertical inArray limit listLen = [ findProd i j | i<-[1..(limit-listLen)], j<-[1..limit]]
            where 
            findProd a b = product [ inArray!(a+k,b) | k<-[0..(listLen-1)] ]

rightDiag inArray limit listLen = [ findProd i j | i<-[1..(limit - listLen)], j<-[1..(limit - listLen)] ]
            where
            findProd a b = product [ inArray!(a+k,b+k) | k<-[0..(listLen-1)] ]

leftDiag inArray limit listLen= [ findProd i j | i <-[1..(limit - listLen)],j<-[listLen..limit] ]
            where
            findProd a b = product [ inArray!(a+k,b-k) | k<-[0..(listLen-1)] ]

solve = do
        x <- readFile "matrix.txt"              
        let limit = 20
        let listLen = 4
        let inArray = listArray ((1,1),(limit,limit)) $ ( map read (words x))
        let maxprod = maximum $ map maximum $ map (\f -> f inArray limit listLen) [horizontal,vertical,rightDiag,leftDiag]
        print inArray
```

Here if I remove the line

`let maxprod = maximum $ map maximum $ map (\f -> f inArray limit listLen) [horizontal,vertical,rightDiag,leftDiag]`

I'm getting a compilation error. How? it is not even related to what I want to print.

Comment: Could you add the compilation error to the question?

Answer (score 5):

The error message you are getting is:

```
Ambiguous type variable `a' in the constraints:
  (Read a) arising from a use of `read' at Temp.hs:23:63-66
  (Show a) arising from a use of `print' at Temp.hs:25:9-13
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

Because you've used `print` the compiler has decided that `inarray` is an instance of `Show`.  Removing the print means it has no way of determining that.

Adding explicit type declarations will help as the type of `read` is `read :: Read a => String -> a` (e.g. it can return anything) and the compiler has no way of nowing this is an instance of `Show`.  I assume you are reading some kind of number as the file is called `matrix.txt`?  You could try something like this.

```
let readInt = read :: String -> Integer
let inArray = listArray ((1,1),(limit,limit)) $ (map readInt (words x))
```

And now the compiler knows that inArray is an array of integers and is thus showable.

Comment: Or equivalently `inArray :: Array (Int,Int) Int`, just *something* to help the compiler decide what specific type to `read`.